# Is there a way to concatenate separated string values in a .txt file using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, concatenation

I have a list in python which contains packages and version numbers, but they're not listed like 'package-0.14' - that is to say, the version numbers are not part of the file name.  It's formatted like this:

> packagename = 0.14

I have another .txt file which has the same information and a whole lot more, which is a problem.  It's formatted like:

> Package: packagename
>
> Package size: 100MB
>
> Version: 0.14

So not only are they line-separated, they have more information between the two values which I need to somehow ignore.  I need the package name and the version number as they relate to each other so I can check that the values from the first list can match the values of the .txt file.

Is there a way in python to say "get the value of 'Package: " and then go line-by-line to get the value of "Version: " so I know it's the version of the same package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parse your file into a dictionary, extract the info from the dict:

```
with open(filename) as f:
   lines=f.readlines()

d=dict()
for line in lines:
  line=line.strip()
  if line:
     (k,v)=line.split(":", 1)
     d[k]=v

print("%s: %s" % (d['Package'], d['Version']))
```

Comment: I like this a lot - I am a little lost in regard to your if statement, though.  What is d[k]=v?  You're setting the value of k to the same-valued index of the dictionary, and then setting that to the value key?

Comment: also, where is 'l' (L) defined?  Sorry, python is kind of new for me

Comment: @jalyper the use of *lowercase L* was just a copy-and-paste error, and should have been `line`. as far as `d[k]=v` is concerned, that's simply assigning the value of `v` to the key in `k` in the dictionay `d`. you should read up on dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Use `re` module.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''

    Package: packagename

    Package size: 100MB

    Version: 0.14
'''
>>> re.findall(r'(?s)\bPackage:\s*(\S+).*?\bVersion:\s*(\S+)', s)
[('packagename', '0.14')]
```